# Git repo converted from SVN has branch folders that should be on git branches

Tags: git, svn

I have converted a `svn` repo to `git` via a command

```
git svn clone http://example.com/svn/software
```

Later, I have realized that I should have used

```
git svn init -t tags -b branches -T trunk http://example.com/svn/software
```

Now, I have a folder containing folders

```
branches
trunk
tags
.git
```

I expected all branches go to a different `git` branch and on top level rather than in a folder on master branch of git.
Can I fix this without connecting to the `svn` repo and clonning again? I prefer fixing it using the current cloned repo.

Comment: Yes, but it will be easier to rerun the clone with `--stdlayout`.

Comment: @Schwern, thanks. What is that way? There is a very slow server and a very large repo. Fixing locally is better even if not straight forward.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time right now to write up an answer. I would suggest starting the process now while you wait on an answer. It might finish first.